# Почему не выполняется mouseMoved действие

Tags: java, swing, mouse-event

При запуске самого простого окна, почему-то не выпоняется событие `mouseMoved`, хотя рядом, с точно таким же условием, находится точно такой-же `mousePressed` и всё выводит.

```
class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    public MainWindow() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                System.out.println("Coords moved: X- " + x + ", Y - " + y);
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                System.out.println("Coords: X- " + x + ", Y - " + y);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У JFrame 3 слушателя мыши :

```
addMouseListener(MouseListener l)
addMouseMotionListener(MouseMotionListener l);
addMouseWheelListener(MouseWheelListener l)
```

Адаптер `MouseAdapter` реализует все 3 эти интерфейса, метод `mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)` относится к `MouseMotionListener` но вы назначаете его только на одно событие `addMouseListener`, вот попробуйте так:

```
class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    public MainWindow() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                System.out.println("Coords moved: X- " + x + ", Y - " + y);
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                System.out.println("Coords: X- " + x + ", Y - " + y);
            }
        };
        addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
    }
}
```